# Figure out how to load 1000 objects in nsmutablearray

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a feed (UITableView) which is partially loaded by quering a database remotely. The database contains 1000 rows which i have to retrieve. I retrieve 10 rows in each query. Results contain text mostly but i store images also for each row. So i start by retrieving the first ten rows and as the user scrolls down the UITableView at the end of the 10th row i make another query to get the next ten rows. So far total 20 rows are stored in my nsmutablearray. This procedure continues until i get 170 rows. Then i get a memory issue in Xcode and the app crashes. So i am trying to figure out how to load all 1000 rows in the UITableView without crashing the app.

I am thinking of deleting the previous 10 rows everytime a new query is done so the nsmutablearray will have always 10 objects. Am i thinking right? I am doing this for the first time.

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Are you reusing your table view cells? How big are the images? Have you used Instruments to see where the memory is going?

Comment: yes i reuse them, about 30kb each, yes i have used instruments i do not get any leaks...xcode gives me this message "CoreAnimation: failed to allocate 2228352 bytes." before my app crash. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're loading a table view, that's not how you do it.  You load the rows on demand in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and let iOS delete the rows that aren't in view.  And when you create a new cell you use `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` and only create a new cell if that call returns a nil.

Elements would be retrieved from your DB on demand, so that you never have more than 15-20 in existing cells in main memory at one time.

In some cases you may have data about individual cells that you want to keep in main memory, but it should generally only be a few small objects per row -- not a problem to fit that much into a 1000-element NSArray.

You DO NOT keep an array of all the cells you create -- iOS does that, and then it will free those that slide off-screen, to preserve storage.

Comment: Thank you! I was using dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier but actually i was saving all my retrieved data to an nsmutablearray for each row including images and then load them to each uitableviewcell so i guess i run out of memory after 1000 objects saved in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought of using core data with NSFetchResultsController? using them together will help you avoid any problems with memory most of the time

Answer (score 0):

I would keep 3 pages of rows in the array. You want 1 page for previous and forward. This will speed up your interface. You don't want to risk the asynchronous interface waiting on a synchronous database call. I also would not be storing images in a database without a super off reason.